# Spark: Issue while reading the parquet file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am getting following exception while reading any parquet file:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Illegal Parquet type: FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY;
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetSchemaConverter.illegalType$1(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetSchemaConverter.convertPrimitiveField(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:193)
```

Found a pull request in apache spark's repo regarding this:
https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/20826

How to fix this?

Comment: can you set spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat option to true while reading parquet in spark?

Answer (score 1):

I agree it's highly annoying. We just serialized it to a String but I agree it's a poor man's solution.